# Thunderbird and multiple email addresses management

Tags: email, thunderbird, addons

I am managing around 30 email addresses. Sometimes I use a wrong email address to send an email then often receive a reply "Who are you ?" afterward.

For example, I always use `email1@gmail.com` to contact my sister, but someday I use `email2@aol.com` by mistake then my sister will get confused.

Thus, I am looking for a way to make Thunderbird warn me if I use the email address which never been used before to contact the receiver. As an example above, Thunderbird will ask me if I really want to send email with `email2@aol.com` because this email has never been used to contact my sister.

I think I want something (maybe a Thunderbird's add-on) that store for each contact email address a list of emails we have used to contact to, then whenever we're going to send an email, if the email address is not in the list Thunderbird will make a warning.

Comment: This looks like a nightmare!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

I use the [Virtual Identity](https://www.absorb.it/virtual-id) extension for a similiar situation, with hundreds of email addresses.

Virtual identity makes the "From:" field editable in the compose window, so you can use any outgoing email address you like.  It will then store the email address that you use, so that the next time you send an email to the same person, it will automatically populate the From field with the correct email address.

If you get an incoming email to an address it has not seen before, when you reply, it will automatically create an identity and use the To: address in the incoming email as the From: address in the reply.

This way, warnings aren't necessary as 99% of the time it just works, and you send from the correct address.  It also means you don't have to set up lots of identities manually in the account settings.